# Random Arithmetic Expressions (Android)

Tags: java, android, math, random, expression

My task is to create an android application where the user is presented with four levels of game diﬃculty.

Is there an easier way to produce this project to include all other difficulties?

Any help is appreciated, Mark

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'd do something recursive like this (pseudocode):

```
private Random rnd;

Expression randomExpression(int numTerms) {
    if (numTerms == 1)
      return LiteralExpression(rnd.nextInt(40 - 1) + 1)
    int split = rnd.nextInt(numTerms - 1) + 1;
    Expression left = randomExpression(split);
    Expression right = randomExpression(numTerms - split);
    Operator op = operators[rnd.nextInt(operators.length)];
    return CompoundExpression(left, op, right);
}
```

Then the top level invocation could randomly choose the `numTerms`suitable for the selected level. Both `CompoundExpression` and `LiteralExpression` would derive from an abstract base class `Expression`, and would take care both of turning their content into a string and of computing the desired result.

The stringification of `CompoundExpression` in particular would take a lot of work if you want to use exactly the minimal number of parentheses required. For that, you'd likely want more information about operators as well, e.g. their precedence and whether they are associative. That's the reason why I chose to make `Operator` a class (or perhaps an `enum`) instead of a simple `char`. Of course, you can at first use a simple stringification which will always enclose a `CompoundExpression` into parentheses, whether it needs them or not. You can always work on simplifying the string once the basic functionality is in place and you can actually see where more work is required.

Comment: Is there any way I can evaluate the expression? and how would I be able to set my text fields accordingly? Many Thanks, Mark

Comment: Evaluate it via a method `Expression.eval()` which you'd have to implement, possibly calling `OPerator.eval(int, int)`. Compute text using `Expression.toString()` which you'd have to implement as outlined in my post, then assign that to the text field. There is no magic here to take that work from you.

Answer (score 1):

Start with generating most basic methods that gives you a number and an integer.

```
public String number(){
  return ""+(r.nextInt(40-1)+1);  
}

public String operator(){
  return ""+(operators[new Random().nextInt(operators.length)]); 
}
```

Now you can build your equations using this method.

level 0 is easy. You can see that it is `number() + operator() + number();`

```
public String level0(){
  return number() + operator() + number();
}
```

next level is `number() + operator() + number() + operator() + number();`.

```
public String level1(){
  return number() + operator() + number() + operator() + number();
}
```

However as you saw it is hard to create this for every level. However as you can see, first part of level 1 is same thing as level 0 (`number() + operator() + number()`). All you do is adding another operator and number to end. You can actually write it like this.

```
public String level1(){
  return level0() + operator() + number();
}
```

But this will also become a burden since there are many levels. An easier way is using recursion. Each level is actually "result of previous level" + operator + number; So nth level is (n-1)th level + operator + number;

```
public String level(int n){
  return level(n-1) + operator() + number();
}
```

If you run this, you will get a stack overflow. Because n will go below 1 and there is no exit condition for your recursion.

```
public String level(int n){
  if(n==1) return number() + operator() + number();
  else return level(n-1) + operator() + number();
}
```

Now if you call level(1) it will simply return soemthing like "2*3". level(2) will return level(1)+operator()+number() which is "2*3"+"-"+"5" which will be "2*3-5"

Comment: Thanks @taytay for your advice. Is there any way I could evaluate this method to produce and answer? I had implemented one method however I could not parse a String expression as an Int. Thanks again for the help, Mark

Comment: I rechecked my code and it has many syntax errors, sorry. I am editting it now